# how to use grafana's "Status panel" with zabbix

Tags: grafana, zabbix

Is there a decision, how to use Grafana's Status panel with zabbix 3.0.3? I do not understand how to send services information from servers to grafana.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send Zabbix informations to Grafana.

You have to configure Grafana to access zabbix's data through APIs or direct mysql connection, you should start from the [official documentation](https://grafana.com/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app) of the plugin.